# Convert int(11) to yyyy-mm-dd format

Tags: php, mysql, xml, date

How can I convert an integer into a date format like `2012-12-12` for insertion in an XML document?

```
<Feed>
<order>
<Order>
<orderid>71</orderid>
<login>krishna</login>
<date>1123213230</date>
```

I've used the below code:

```
$_xml .= "\t<date>" . $n['date'] . "</date>\r\n";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `FROM_UNIXTIME(column_name, '%Y-%m-%d')` in your MySQL query.

Or you can just use `date('Y-m-d', $n['date'])`.

Also, you can use [`PHP_EOL`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) and you won't have to manually add `"\r\n"` to the end of your strings.

Comment: @minitech, thanks for the edit contribution! I seem to forget a lot that you can add links to text _within_ code annotations. -.-

Comment: Yeah, too bad Markdown can't do it, though. It would be nicer :P

Comment: @minitech Also, I just remembered that the d and m are lowercase in MySQL conversions as well.  The capital M gives the month name if I'm not mistaken. I can't keep track of all these date conversion options.